# Do I have to restart mysql server after changing login password?

Tags: php, mysql

I changed the password which is needed to login the mariaDB and in ssh I changed config.php file.

```
 define('DB_PASSWORD', 'new password');
```

and when entering my page it said fail to connect to the database. I think mysql service needs to be restarted but it requires root authority and I don't know what root's password is. Is there other ways to connect to the database in ftp server or know the root's password?

Answer (score 1):

use `FLUSH PRIVILEGES;` command in mariaDB.

https://mariadb.com/kb/en/mariadb/flush/

Comment: I tried to give 'reload' priviliege for 'flush privilege', but I got 'Access denied for user 'username'@'%' (using password: YES)' with ERROR 1045. Is this because the user doesn't have root authority?

Comment: It shows your login to mariadb fails. It is no relation with root privilege.